# Generating lambda expressions in nsubstitute mocking

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I am trying to get an NSubstitue object I have to mock a function by using another. (For example, I want an identity function getting a single string, and returning it)

Suppose I had a class foo with function bar getting a single int, and returning a single int, how would I create a mock of it which would return the value it got for every input?

In particular, given an interface:

```
public interface ifoo 
{
   public int func(int x) { ... }
}
```

Could I create a mock of it using NSubstitute, and make the function func returh for every x, that x? (i.e. f(x) = x)

Comment: This is possible (as per the answer below), but in this case it would be simplest to avoid a mocking library for this. i.e. `class IdFoo : ifoo { public int func(int x) => x; }` then use an instance of that for your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `CallInfo` to return the argument in the first position

```
var subst = Substitute.For<ifoo>();
subst.func(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(info => info.ArgAt<int>(0));
var test = subst.func(10);
```